# ArrayList convert to IEnumerable of Double

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert an ArrayList into a IEnumerable with doubles but what I have its not working.. how can I do this?

from load I have this

```
myAL(1) = New ArrayList
```

from a button I have this

```
Dim data As IEnumerable(Of Double) = myAL(1).Cast
```

Comment: You should not use `ArrayList`.

Comment: what should I use that has RemoveAt ?

Comment: @PaulWill `IEnumerable(Of T)` has [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to convert an `ArrayList` to an `IEnumerable(Of Double)` is:

```
Dim data As IEnumerable(Of Double) = myAL(1).Cast(Of Double)()
```

However, as SLaks mentions, `ArrayList` should be avoided.  Instead, use [`System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`, so no conversion is required, and it also supports `RemoveAt`.